# MongoDB - ReferenceError: startsWithDigit is not defined

Tags: mongodb

Im working on a side project for myself and in my URL Shortener I get an error on our stats page (Example: http://xd6.co/u/ah/stats) which seems to show up only after the link is created for some time/accumulates clicks, then it gets the error message below:

```
ReferenceError: startsWithDigit is not defined
    at Object.eval [as toVersionString] (eval at makeFunction (/home/xd6/node_modules/mongolian/node_modules/buffalo/lib/bson.js:380:17))
    at Object.eval [as toString] (eval at makeFunction (/home/xd6/node_modules/mongolian/node_modules/buffalo/lib/bson.js:380:17))
    at String (unknown source)
    at Writer._name (/home/xd6/node_modules/mustache/mustache.js:292:35)
    at Writer._escaped (/home/xd6/node_modules/mustache/mustache.js:296:32)
    at renderFunction (/home/xd6/node_modules/mustache/mustache.js:357:28)
    at subRenders.(anonymous function) (/home/xd6/node_modules/mustache/mustache.js:328:18)
    at Writer._section (/home/xd6/node_modules/mustache/mustache.js:240:21)
    at renderFunction (/home/xd6/node_modules/mustache/mustache.js:345:28)
    at Writer._compile.cache.(anonymous function) (/home/xd6/node_modules/mustache/mustache.js:224:16)
    at Writer.render (/home/xd6/node_modules/mustache/mustache.js:204:34)
    at Object.exports.render (/home/xd6/node_modules/mustache/mustache.js:596:20)
```

And when I run mongo in the console and do `db.urls.find()` I get this in response:

```
{ "short" : "aa", "long" : "http://xd6.co/Projects/url-shortener", "created" : "2013-01-03 7:11 UTC", "clicks" : 0, "visitors" : [ ], "subscribers" : [ ], "_id" : ObjectId("50e52f2b000000d358000002") }
{ "short" : "ab", "long" : "http://google.com", "created" : "2013-01-06 1:17 UTC", "clicks" : 0, "visitors" : [ ], "subscribers" : [ ], "_id" : ObjectId("50e8d0c2000000d358000003") }
{ "short" : "ac", "long" : "http://xd6.co/u/", "created" : "2013-01-07 5:54 UTC", "clicks" : 0, "visitors" : [ ], "subscribers" : [ ], "_id" : ObjectId("50ea6332000000435b000002") }
ReferenceError: startsWithDigit is not defined
```

Which shows that it's a mongo error and not something wrong in our code. Also the Mongo in the console is giving out different results then the nodejs program itself. It's not even showing all of the existing documents that do exist, for example "ae" is not existant in the mongo console output, but the nodejs is obviously finding data somewhere for it (http://xd6.co/u/api/ae/stats).

It also seems to only be an issue with the urls collection since the other two collections we have in the database don't return the error.

Before someone comments on possibly using the wrong db/collection to explain where nodejs is finding the other data (using XD6 DB and urls collection):

```
> show dbs
XD6 0.0625GB
local   (empty)
test    (empty)
> use XD6
switched to db XD6
> show collections
pages
posts
system.indexes
urls
```

Comment: Did you try validating the collection:  `db.urls.validate(true)`?  If it reports problems you can try and [repair](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/#repairDatabase) the database.

Comment: Doesn't look like it has any errors, it returned with `"valid" : true, "errors" : [ ], "ok" : 1` at the end. Full output here: http://pastebin.com/b20PnUHv

Answer (score 0):

Can you actually start from a clean db and reproduce this with some code ? Have you defined some sort of javascript function called startsWithDigit

Comment: I restarted from a clean database and get the same issue, and no I have not defined a function with that name, it actually shows the same error in the mongo database if you didn't notice, meaning it isn't in my code. However when I removed the geoip variables that were being added to the database it seemed that the error went away. If you'd like I can maybe post a snippet on pastebin. (It's written NodeJS).

Comment: actually if you can reproduce it just using the console from an empty db it would be better and also what kind server version and os you are using. If it's reproducible it might be a server bug.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 on Xen VPS. Also I really think that the error is coming from the useragent/geoip data going into the mongodb since when I comment that out in the nodejs it doesn't seem to break the database.

Comment: yeah looks like it's got something to do with what you are actually inserting I just read through the mongodb code and there is no method called startsWithDigit. you might want to sanitize the results before inserting them into Mongodb

Comment: Any idea of how to sanitize the data in NodeJS? I'm inserting in JSON. (http://pastebin.com/UtjXQHEf) for the block of code that causes the issue. Right at `urls.update({short: req.params.short},                                           {'$set': {clicks: url.clicks + 1},                                                '$push': {visitors: visitor}});` If I remove visitors, it doesn't break the database.